# Handling million of row

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Hi recently I need to handle market data by importing it from different kind of exchange and analysis it

The market table is pretty simple it consist of below column

```
market_name varchar(45) => this will be exchange name
market_type varchar(5) => buy sell bids of asks 
currency varchar(8) => cur1_cur2 e.g usd_eur
volume decimal(30,10) 
price decimal(30,10)
import_time int => unix time
```

Due to some limitation in protocol of getting the data from different exchange, I can only at best update the data every 5seconds.

Now the problem is this :

Every 5 second for one exchange I will import two market type buy and sell.
Every market type will have 100 record.

So for one day for one exchange I will be importing

```
( 86400 / 5 ) * 2 * 100 = 3,456,000 row
```

For one month I'll be importing

```
3,456,000 * 30 = 10,368,000 row
```

currently we have 5 exchange with 2 currency each which means we will import around 100,368,000 row in one month.

Now for the analysis currently we will output below data :

1. Last imported data for selected exchange ( 2 - 4 ) and one currency , which is simple.
2. One day data for selected exchange ( 2 - 4 ) and selected one currency.
3. same as above but with data more than one month less than a year.

You will see that some data will not be use for now, but we still need to kept it for future usage.

Any advice of best way to handling this ?

Currently I always using MySQL as my database, but I'm not sure it's the correct DB to handling this.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.  Normalize.  Change market_name and market_type and currency from a bulky VARCHAR into an ENUM or a TINYINT.  This will cut the datasize in half.  DECIMAL(30,10) takes 14 bytes and has far more precision than is needed.  Find out what the largest value is.  Are the decimal places limited to 2 digits as is currently common in the US?  Or do you need more decimal places.  Will FLOAT (4 bytes, about 7 significant digits) do?  That change will also save a lot.

Step 2.  Decide whether you need the data "forever".  If not, what is the "purge" policy?  It would probably be good to PARTITION by MONTH.  This would make purging easy and very fast, plus it might help in some of the queries.

Step 3.  Please show us the actual SELECTs; we need to further tune them, plus see what other shrinkage/optimizations/etc can be done.

Step 4.  Would "summary tables" help?  That is, rather than keeping 5-sec data for last month, would 1-minute, or even 1-hour, data suffice?  That would save a huge amount of space, and tremendously speed up the queries.

Step 5.  After deciding on PARTITIONing and the SELECTs, let's discuss the INDEXes.

I can elaborate on any of these; which ones would you like more details on?

Comment: Step 1 : Good idea on Normalize, I can make the decimal smaller around 4. I heard Float have bad reputation on calculating price related number

Step 2 : Thats the problem we don't know yet so just keep everything :D

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Good idea on Normalize, I can make the decimal smaller around 4. I heard Float have bad reputation on calculating price related number

Step 2 : Thats the problem we don't know yet so just keep everything :D

Step 3 : We updated to only save 15 minute each by getting the OHLC price from all that 5 sec, so now should be much less data saved.

Step 4 : I gave them 1 minute and they said its to slow , LOL.

Step 5 : Almost index everything except price and volume

I would prefer the SELECT one, since it usually very slow :D, I put the select in below Answer later.

Comment: Indexing everything is stupid. You index what **should be indexed**, otherwise you end up with garbage that takes up memory, storage and CPU time. But the most important thing ever is to **configure** your MySQL properly to handle the load. Every software that exists runs on hardware. You need to allow the software to utilize that hardware. You also need proper hardware for such purpose. And that's the part you skipped entirely in your question and in your answer.

Comment: 1-minute summary tables should be about 12 times as fast as 5-second raw data.  If it was not, let's dig into the details.

Comment: I summarize every 15 minute, but going to 5 minuteif it,s not reflecting the real market anymore

Answer (score 0):

My data is change to this structure

```
market_name varchar(45)
market_currency_pair varchar(10)
market_type varchar(5)
market_time datetime
market_position_id int(11)
average_volume decimal(30,10)
open_value decimal(30,10)
high_value decimal(30,10)
low_value decimal(30,10)
close_value decimal(30,10)
```

I can reduce some of the column :D, by the way how you calculate the byte for each type ?

I don't have the select query yet, but this is the scenario :

1. Selecting OHLC price of each market filter by how much volume you want to see that calculated by summing average_volume.
2. Selecting O/H/L/C price of 2 to 4 market filter by how much volume you want to see that calculated by summing average volume.

My most concern is whether I save the correct data, this is what I grep every 5s ( v is volume, p is price )

```
market_position_id   first 5s   second 5s   third 5s   ...  last 5s
1                   v:10,p:20   v:11,p:30   v:8,p:16        v:12,p:15
2                   v:11,p:30   v:12,p:28   v:10,p:17       v:11,p:14
and so on
```

Then I summarize like this which will be save to above table:

```
market_position_id  average_volume  open  high  low  close
1                   9.6             20    30    15   15
2                   11              30    30    14   14 
and so on
```

Comment: OK, FLOAT is not appropriate.  But DECIMAL(30,10) is too big.  I have not heard of a stop going larger than 6 digits to the left of the decimal point, and perhaps only 4 to the right (since things went decimal a decade ago).  That would be DECIMAL(10,4) -- 5 bytes.  Volume should perhaps be DECIMAL(11,0) (5 bytes) or BIGINT (8 bytes).  "average_volume" could be FLOAT or DOUBLE (8 bytes).

Comment: DATATYPE sizes:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html and etc.  DECIMAL(m,n) occupies _approximately_ m/2 bytes.

Comment: Its cryto currency , and there is a fight between use decimal or bigint. Which mean I'll use the small one, same for both price and vol.

Comment: I mean it need to be able to handle both fiat and crypto currency , both in volumn and price column

Answer (score -1):

You slipped a decimal ... 30 * 3,456,000 = 103,680,000 rows per month per exchange, not easily indexable.  With 5 exchanges and 2 currencies, that is 1,036,800,000 rows per month.

This looks to me like a definite start for a bigdata project.  It is already structured perfectly for any hadoop based solution.  You will need to look a a wide but shallow cluster architecture with good sharding.

Depending on the need for transactional integrity, a hive (sql against raw files dumped into the HDFS partition), hBase (aka Amazon technology) or Cassandra  (aka Facebook Technology derived from Amazon technology) abstraction layer might make sense.  I would need to know more about the product before suggesting which way to jump.

On the other hand, Instagram runs just fine on postgresql, and their CTO has a blog detailing what they have done to scale it our and the headaches they have had to deal with.

Comment: In the future I will invest time on hadoop, we really don't have the resource right now. So we just do whatever work and fast :D